# Object still up

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I'm using Angular to display a table of users. I created a form to add and edit users. When a user row is clicked I'm passing that particular user to a function in my controller:

```
$scope.editUser = function (selectedUser) {
    $scope.userToAdd = selectedUser;
};
```

In the above function I create a new object $scope.userToAdd. The problem is that once selectedUser is passed into $scope.userToAdd changes that happen in a form bound to userToAdd are being reflected in selectedUser. This is causing me trouble because when someone changes a value and then clicks cancel; the changes are now reflected on the user table. What is the Angular best practice for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`angular.copy`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.copy) to make a copy of the user you are editing.  Then, when they click save, you copy the user back:

```js
$scope.editUser = function (selectedUser) {
    // Note: you might want to save the user's index or something so you can
    // know where to return the user, like this:
    $scope.userToAdd = angular.copy(selectedUser);
};
```

If you are rendering the user in a loop, you can do something like this:

```html
<li ng-repeat="user in users">
    ...
    <button ngclick="editUser(user, $index);">Edit</button>
</li>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$scope.editUser = function(selectedUser, index) {
    // Note: you might want to save the user's index or something so you can
    // know where to return the user, like this:
    $scope.userToAdd = angular.copy(selectedUser);
    $scope.userToAddIndex = index;
};

$scope.saveUser = function() {
    // You may want to user angular.copy() here again, to prevent accidental
    // modification of the user.
    $scope.users[$scope.userToAddIndex] = $scope.userToAdd;
};
```